# SQL double match function and pulling in values

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I have two tables in Access, Master Data and Current Data. 
They both have columns "key" in them. Master data also has "From date" and "To Date" columns. Current Data has "Creation Date" column. I need to match two tables and for every "Key" match between the tables, I need the code to take a creation date and figure out if that date is between the To and from date in the master file. If it the creation date doesnt fall between the to and from date, then I need all those rows to show up in the query. 
This is what I have so far (this code is pulling the match between the tables for the key tab)

```
SELECT
 us.*
FROM [SAP Data] us
INNER JOIN [Master Data] uss ON uss.Key = us.Key
```

I can't figure out how to transition from this and further tell it to match the dates and see if the date falls between to-from dates in the master file. Is there anyone who could have any guidance as to how I could proceed?

Comment: Sample data and desired results are a welcome addition to most questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `not exists`:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM [Current Data] as cd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [Master Data] as md
                  WHERE cd.Key = md.Key AND
                        md.[Creation Date] BETWEEN md.FromDate and md.ToDate
                 );
```

Comment: Gordon, I think OP wants the `Current Data` that's not in the Master Data. That's how I interpret it anyways.

Comment: @WEI_DBA . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  I agree and changed the answer.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thanks for the help. And sorry for not including the sample data. This definitely works and looks like exactly what's needed except when I try to run it, it asks me to enter a parameter value for the creation date. I was trying to use the creation date from the original matched values ("key" match between both tables). So it would match the two tables, and then use the dates from the results..I'm not sure if that makes sense. Let me know if it doesnt. English isnt my first language

Comment: @KateLO . . . Be sure the column names are spelled correctly in the query.  It shouldn't be asking you for parameters if they are correct.